# C++ function that returns an array of pointers to another function

Tags: c++

I have a BFS search function in which I declare an array `visited` of pointers to a `struct Edge`. I want to send that array of pointers to another function in order to access the struct members. 
The problem is that I can't access `visited[i]->cap`.
I know that the scope of the array `visited` is local. From what I understand it shouldn't effect anything since I create a new array object (in the while loop in the FordFulkerson function) and should "copy" the results? I just can't seem to figure out how to fix it. Any hits, explanations would be great.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code. I now use an `std::array<Edge*,20001> visited`. The problem is that for some reason I am still getting null pointers. Can anyone see why?

The above code that is in the BFS function should prevent that and give me my path back to where I started. Am I totally wrong?

```
/* Edge structure. Includes reverseEdge*/
struct Edge 
{
int u;
int v;
int cap;
int flow;
struct Edge* reverseEdge;

Edge(int u, int v, int cap)
{
    this->u = u;
    this->v = v;
    this->cap = cap;
    this->flow = 0;
}
};

int FordFulkerson(int s, int t, array<vector<Edge*>, 20001> &adjacencyList, array<Edge*, 20001> &visited)
{
    int flow = 0;
    int b = INT_MAX;
    while (BFS(s, t, adjacencyList, visited))
    {
        if (visited[t] != nullptr)
        {
            for (int i = t; t != s; i = visited[i]->u)
            {
                b = min(b,(visited[i]->cap) - (visited[i]->flow));
            }
            for (int i = t; t != s; i = visited[i]->u)
            {
                visited[i]->flow += b; 
                visited[i]->reverseEdge->flow -= b; 
            }
            flow += b;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}


/* BFS that returns a pointer to an array of pointers to edge (two levels of indirection) */
bool BFS(int s, int t, array<vector<Edge*>, 20001> &adjacencyList, array<Edge*, 20001> &visited)
{
    queue<int> Q;
    Q.push(s);
    int n = 0;
    while (!Q.empty())
    {
        int currentNode = Q.front(); 
        Q.pop();
        for (Edge *e : adjacencyList[currentNode])
        {
            if (e == nullptr)
            {
                //DO NOTHING
            }
            else{
                if (visited[e->v] == nullptr && (e->cap) > (e->flow))
                {
                    visited[e->v] = e;
                    Q.push(e->v);
                    if (e->v == t)
                    {
                        //clear queue here!
                        clearQueue(Q);
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    //clear queue here!
    clearQueue(Q);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The array `visited` is a local variable within the `BFS` function, returning a pointer to it will not work as the array will go out of scope when you return from the function. Either use `std::array` if you want a fixed-sized array you can pass around, or `std::vector` if you want a dynamic array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks. Is it ok to declare it in the BFS function or must I send it as an argument?

Comment: If you insist on using a C-style array you either need to allocate it dynamically in the function or pass it in as an argument. I still recommend you change to use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am thinking of this  ´array<Edge*, 20001> visited = { nullptr };´ and sending it as a parameter

Comment: If you pass it as an argument, remember that it should be a reference. Other than that it's fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your help :)